# How to move old Gmail attachments to Google Drive?

Tags: gmail, google-drive

Gmail and Google Drive is sharing storage. Is there a way to move old Gmail attachments into Google Drive, such that I can manage attachments in Google Drive instead of in Gmail?

Comment: There isn't seperate storage this question makes no sense it's also not on topic

Comment: There exist a script file for Google Docs that does this though

Comment: What do you mean by "makes no sense"? Can you remove attachments from Gmails at the same convenience level of use folder view in Google Drive to remove files?

Comment: Gmail attachments cannot be removed from an email.  You can send the file to your Google Drive of course so it can be accessed from the Google Drive folder otherwise its not accessible from that folder.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound), GMail and Google Drive storage is shared, so it doesn't make sense to try to move GMail attachments to Google Drive in order to save on GMail space.

However, using [Slimbox](https://rok.strnisa.com/slimbox/), you can:

- **Download** your GMail/Inbox attachments to your computer.
- **Optionally remove** them from the original emails.
- **Copy** attachments to your own or another cloud storage.

Through unique keys, it is easy to then:

- **Find attachments** using original emails (which now mentions the files removed).
- **Find original emails** using attachment names.

Disclaimer: I wrote the tool. Feedback welcome.

Answer (score 0):

On attachments in Gmail there's an icon that let's you save it into your Drive Account, then delete the email.

[image]